# Is there any possible undefined behaviour if I use `std::string` to store any bytes?

Tags: c++, stl, undefined-behavior

Is there any possible undefined behaviour if I use `std::string` to store any bytes like using a `std::vector`?

Comment: The only possible issue is that `char` is potentially a signed quantity and bytes are often thought of as unsigned. Apart from that there are no issues. But you should ask yourself what is the benefit of `std::string` over `std::vector<uint8_t>`

Comment: In general you should be fine. But in theory UB is almost always possible like std::string::data() gives you a pointer that you can dereference out of range.

Comment: UB, unlikely. But it can lead people to misuse and misunderstand the code.

Comment: Sure, you can abuse `std::string` to store `char`s instead of vectors, but in my mind, it doesn't make sense to store anything other than printable characters in a `std::string`. Whenever I see `std::string`, I think there's a general assumption made that whatever is in there can be seen, and if it can't, there's a problem.

Comment: Can you give us some more context: why do you want/need to do this ?

Comment: As long as you use your collection to store bytes in, there will be no undefined behavior. But if you used other string abilities, then you will have undefined behaviors; for examples, 0x00 has a special meaning, `end()` can be dereferenced... So if you need to use a byte array, **using `vector` is much less risky than `string`**.

Comment: @dalfaB *"if you used other string abilities, then you will have undefined behaviors"* Can you be more specific? Embedded nulls shouldn't cause UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I agree, the examples I've given do not made directly UBs. The idea is when is std::string we may be tempted of using string capacities, like c_str() and then the presence of null characters will give unexpected results. So I agree this is not UB.